# Checking condition in IF vs WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem and I have 2 solutions for that problem. I have to write a procedure which will return rows falling into required categories. The required categories will be passed as boolean (or bit) values. The first solution is:-

```
DECLARE @IsRowType1Req bit;
DECLARE @IsRowType2Req bit;

DECLARE @tbl1 table (ID int, RowType varchar(50));

DECLARE @tmpTbl table (ID int, RowType varchar(50));

IF @IsRowType1Req = 1
    INSERT INTO
        @tmpTbl
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        @tbl1 
    WHERE 
        RowType = 'RowType1';

IF @IsRowType2Req = 1
    INSERT INTO
        @tmpTbl
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        @tbl1 
    WHERE 
        RowType = 'RowType2';

SELECT * FROM @tmpTbl;
```

Now, this solution uses IF clause to select only required type of rows. The other one is:-

```
DECLARE @IsRowType1Req bit;
DECLARE @IsRowType2Req bit;

DECLARE @tbl1 table (ID int, RowType varchar(50));

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    @tbl1 
WHERE 
    RowType = 'RowType1' AND 
    @IsRowType1Req = 1

UNION

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    @tbl1 
WHERE 
    RowType = 'RowType2' AND 
    @IsRowType2Req = 1
```

This solution utilizes WHERE clause to restrict unwanted type of rows. Can anybody please tell me which one will be faster and why?

Comment: SQL Server uses **T-SQL** as its programming language - *not* PL/SQL as you mention in your title....

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that.

Comment: Are you sure you want UNION and not UNION ALL? UNION is more expensive as duplicates are removed. (UNION ALL does the same as your if solution.)

Comment: What if both bits are 0? What do you return?

Comment: @jarlh, if UNION ALL is less expensive, I would like to go with that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would likely depend on the size of the table as well as the size of each subset returned.

The IF solution has to insert rows into another table, which doesn't come cheap. The WHERE solution, on the other hand, uses UNION which implies sorting to remove duplicate entries. If you replaced UNION with UNION ALL (which you could safely do because your two subsets would never have duplicates), the WHERE solution would become the better one of the two hands down.

However, since rows in `@tbl1` cannot be more than one type, you could solve the problem differently. You could match `@tbl1` against a dynamically built table consisting of 0, 1 or 2 rows depending on the values of `@IsRowType1Req` and `@IsRowType2Req`. You would build that table like this:

```
SELECT 'RowType1' WHERE @IsRowType1Req = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'RowType2' WHERE @IsRowType2Req = 1
```

and then join it to `@tbl1`:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    @tbl1 AS t
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT 'RowType1' WHERE @IsRowType1Req = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'RowType2' WHERE @IsRowType2Req = 1
    ) AS f (RowType)
ON
    t.RowType = f.RowType
;
```

In a way, this might mean that WHERE still "wins", but you could rewrite the virtual table without using WHERE:

```
SELECT CASE @IsRowType1Req WHEN 1 THEN 'RowType1' END
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE @IsRowType2Req WHEN 1 THEN 'RowType2' END
```

or like this, using the VALUES constructor introduced in SQL Server 2008:

```
VALUES
    (CASE @IsRowType1Req WHEN 1 THEN 'RowType1' END),
    (CASE @IsRowType2Req WHEN 1 THEN 'RowType2' END)
```

That way the table would always consist of 2 rows, each row containing either a requested type or NULL. The result of the join with that table would still be the same and match your desired result.

Answer (score 2):

With the information you have given there seems no need to use a `UNION`of `IF`.

```
SELECT *
FROM @tbl1
WHERE
  (RowType = 'RowType2' AND @IsRowType2Req = 1)
  OR (RowType = 'RowType1' AND @IsRowType1Req = 1);
```

Comment: You sure it won't run for all of the rows in `@tbl1` even if `@IsRowType2Req` or `@IsRowType1Req` are false? I guess that would be expensive.

Comment: It would have to go through every row to determine if the conditions are met yes. But the same goes for the `UNION` and `IF` solutions in your question.

Comment: Not in `IF` solution.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would go with the IF, but only because you are using the UNION clause and that means your are going to run two single queries and then combine the results.

If fact, when you use UNION, SQL Server needs to make sure the combined result set does not contain any duplicated rows, so it needs to run both queries and then compare the result set to check for coincidences.

Here you have a detailed explanation http://webbtechsolutions.com/2009/08/06/the-effects-union-in-a-sql-query/